# Joomla 3.6 Не отображается главная страница

Tags: php, joomla, шаблоны, joomla3

Я только начал осваивать Joomla!

Хедер, меню, футер я сделал. Так же между ними написал

```
<jdoc:include type="component"/>
```

Но отображаетсся какое-то предложение из шаблона.(это не ошибка)
В материалах у меня только один мною созданный.
Создал категорию и только она одна активирована.

Поставил макисмальный приоритет показа ошибок в настройках - их нет. Я что-то не так делаю, не могу понять, откуда взялся тот текст. Даже в папке templates удалил все, кроме своего шаблона и system

Comment: так у пункта меню "главная" какой тип стоит, какой компонент должен выводиться на главной? Возможно материал, а этот текст - это и есть текст этого материала?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич Спасибо. У меня лендинг и якоря, вместо пунктов, поэтому главную не создал. Теперь все рабоатет :)